# How to do a transpose of this query result

Tags: oracle, row, multiple-columns

I am trying to do a transpose in oracle 11g for this

```
CategoryId    TypeId       PercentageFrom     Percentage To    CategoryDesc       TypeDesc 
2             3             0                  10              Silver             High Priority
2             2             0                  14              Silver             Medium Priority
2             1             0                  0.5             Silver             Low Priority
3             3             10.01              20              Gold             High Priority
3             2             14.01             23               Gold             Medium Priority
3             1             0.51              1                Gold             Low Priority
4             3             20.01             30               Platinum             High Priority
4             2             23.1              43               Platinum             Medium Priority
4             1             1.01              3               Platinum             Low Priority
```

Into something like

```
High  Medium  Low       Rules
10     14      0.5     Silver
20     23      1       Gold
30     43      3       Platinum
```

Please help guys i am new to Oracle and not sure how to go ahead with this

Comment: You need `PIVOT` operation. There are so many answers already available here is SO.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, Thanks for your reply. I am trying to generate my output using PIVOT for long time, it seems as I am new to oracle I am not able to grasp the syntax or how to of oracle. I am continuing to try, but if you have any specific inputs that would be greatly appreciated.